# How can I initialize a database when using EF MF?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-model-first

I have an application using EF 4.1 (using the model-first flavour), and I want to initialize the database when the model is updated and the database is dropped and re-created.

I've spent hours trying to find decent documentation on this, and I thought that Database.SetInitializer was the way to go, but it turns out that this requires a DbContext, and the code that's been generated uses ObjectContext.

I believe that I can fiddle about under the hood to switch the T4 templates to use DbContext, but surely there must be a way to work with the out-of-the-box model-first generated code?

[Should I just abandon model-first altogether?]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call Database.SetInitializer on model-first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206058/how-to-call-database-setinitializer-on-model-first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model first approach doesn't have any automatic database generation.

When you are using model first you simply right click in the designer pane and select *Generate database from model*. It will create database script which you can execute to create a database. There is additional plugin for VS2010 called [Database Generation Power Pack](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87) which allows some more advanced scenarios like generating change script between the existing database and your model but this tool requires at least VS2010 Premium.